# IOS: Can't create directory, nsstring striping slash

Tags: ios, path, nsstring, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a directory to download some pdf-files. I have been using the same technic in other classes and its work. But in 1 specific class where I am trying to make 2 subdirectories but the NSString is striping the last slash in the path.

I use this method:

```
- (NSString*)checkDirectory:(NSString*)path {
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL isDir = YES;
NSString *string = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"/Documents" stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@/",path]];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:string isDirectory:&isDir]){
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:string withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error %@",error);
    }
}
return string;
}
```

Where the variable path is looking like:

```
/Reports/year2012/38week/
```

But at the moment I append the path component to NSHomeDirectory() the string strip off the slash and producing that the app can't create the dorectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the intermediate directory value to YES

```
withIntermediateDirectories:YES
```